# Why is EF DataBase First not use getdate()?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am using EF 4.1 with database first.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Product(
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
   Title nvarchar(200) not null,
   CreateDate datetime not null default(getdate()),
)
```

When I add a new row, I get an exception about DateTime type overflow.

The `getdate()` of database settings is invalid.

I must be set the `storeGeneatePattern` property of the `createdate` field to `Computed`.

Is there any way to let the EF automatically generated the `DateTime` column without manually set??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No EF will never use your database default. The reason is that your entity has non nullable `DateTime` property. This property has by default assigned default value in .NET which is 1.1.0001. EF doesn't know if you assigned that value or if it is default value so it always explicitly passes this value to the database. Same happens if you use nullable type but in this case EF will pass explicitly null. In both cases default value from database will not be applied because that value is applied only when the value from application is not explicitly passed in an insert command - EF explicitly passes all values from entity.

Comment: Reason enough not to use EF in any serious application for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your `Product` entity class constructor,

```
public class Product{
  public Product(){
     CreateDate =DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this, but when there are multiple similar fields the workload is very large.
 Can EF just use "getdate()" of database setting without manually set?