# Entity Framework 6 Entities and Table Constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table that has a constant on it that calls getdate() whenever a record is inserted in sql. I just figured I would just map the table and entity framework would pick up on that fact that there was a constraint on that column and let SQL worry about it. But instead it inserts a date.minvalue if I don't put anything in that field myself. I was wondering why it doesn't detect the constraint or maybe I need to do something to so it does ? What I am I missing I am disappointed in EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the computed attribute to the property in the model class:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

If you are using fluent mapping, use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ModelClass>().Property(t => t.PropertyName)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
```

Comment: I guess I am just surprised this isn't set when the model is generated ? Does it not make since for EF to do this automatically ?

Comment: If you are doing things Code-First, then you must set up everything manually. If you are using database-first, I would expect it to pick up the constraint.

Comment: This is database first

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10293974/2823539 . Looks like this could be a limitation. I have seen it work with Code-First, but haven't tried with database first.

Comment: Great find! wish his answer wasn't true :)

Comment: why your question doesn't have any tag